# Bootstrap: creating a grid of icons

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I need to create a grid of icons which does NOT stack when viewed on mobile.
I've this setup right now:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li class="span3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">Element1
                    <br />
                </div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70" alt="Element1" />
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="span3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">Element2
                    <br />
                </div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70" alt="Element2" />
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="span3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">Element3
                    <br />
                </div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70" alt="Element3" />
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="span3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">Element4
                    <br />
                </div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70" alt="Element4" />
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

But when the output window is below a certain width all the icons are stacked one above the other. I'd like to have them inline since they're very small, like on the desktop version.
What's the best way to do that?

One more request, but less important: icons number may vary. They can be from 1 to 4 or even more (no problem in displaying 2 rows). Is there a *bootstrap* (or css) way to have them centered when they're less than 4 in a row?

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/hpfbhfgj/)

Comment: Is there a very specific reason why you're using 2.3? Bootstrap 3+ easily solves this.

Comment: Yes, my template is based on that version and the upgrade isn't flawless

Comment: I would try overriding the media query for the span. In this case, I would do something like `.thumbnail .span3` and then do a percentage (25%) so it's intact.

Comment: Can you explain? I tried adding `width:25%` to the `li` element but all I get is just a left align

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to not use bootstrap classes for this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="thumbnails">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">Element1</div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70" alt="Element1" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">Element2</div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70" alt="Element2" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">Element3</div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70" alt="Element3" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">Element4</div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70" alt="Element4" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.thumbnails {text-align: center;}
.thumbnails .thumbnail {display: inline-block; margin: 0 5px;}
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/hap4vvex/

*Note: The thumbnails don't take up the full width, but they do center with any number*

Comment: the jsfiddle was not up to date with your answer, but fixing it works

Comment: I didnt really **require** bootstrap classes, this solution is simply and I like it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using some old Bootstrap classes.

I haven't tested this code but try http://pastebin.com/SuiuK2pN